# ffmpeg version 2.8.4 "zoompan" error, didn't occur in 2.6

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

After upgrading to the latest version of ffmpeg version 2.8.4, I now get an error with the "zoompan" complex filter. This ran fine on an earlier version (2.6). If I remove that particular command the process runs.

#### Line that causes the error:

```
zoompan=z="min(zoom+0.0015\,1.5)":d=700:x="if(gte(zoom\,1.5)\,x\,x+1/a)": y="if(gte(zoom\,1.5)\,y\,y+1)":s=1280x720'
```

#### Entire command

```
          cmd =   'ffmpeg'
          cmd +=  ' -loop 1 -i ' + base_images[0] + ' -loop 1 -i ' + base_images[1] +  ' -loop 1 -i ' + base_images[2] +  ' -loop 1 -i ' + base_images[3] 
          cmd +=  ' -filter_complex " '
          cmd +=  ' nullsrc=size=1280x760 [base]; '
          cmd +=  '[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=640x380 [upperleft];'
          cmd +=  '[1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=640x380 [upperright];'
          cmd +=  '[2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=640x380 [lowerleft];'
          cmd +=  '[3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=640x380 [lowerright];'
          cmd +=  '[base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1];'
          cmd +=  '[tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=1:x=640 [tmp2];'
          cmd +=  '[tmp2][lowerleft] overlay=shortest=1:y=380 [tmp3];'
          cmd +=  '[tmp3][lowerright] overlay=shortest=1:x=640:y=380"'
          cmd +=   ',zoompan=z="min(zoom+0.0015\,1.5)":d=700:x="if(gte(zoom\,1.5)\,x\,x+1/a)":y="if(gte(zoom\,1.5)\,y\,y+1)":s=1280x720'
          cmd +=  ',drawbox=enable="gt(t\,1)*lt(t\,7)":x="(iw/6)":y="(ih/2)-100":color=black@0.7:width=iw/1.5:height=100:t=max'
          cmd +=  ',drawbox=enable="gt(t\,1)*lt(t\,7)":x="(iw/3)":y="(ih/1.9)":color=black@0.7:width=iw/3:height=110:t=max'
          cmd +=  ',"drawtext=fontfile=' + fontfile + ':fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h-line_h)/2.2:text=' + "The End" + ':fontsize=38","drawtext=fontfile=' + fontfile + ':fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h-line_h)/1.7:text=' + create_date[0] + ':fontsize=28","drawtext=fontfile=' + fontfile + ':fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h-line_h)/1.5:text=' + create_date[1] + ':fontsize=28","fps=30"'
          cmd +=   ' -t 5 -c:v libx264 -y ' + theend_video
```

#### Error message

```
[swscaler @ 0x7fd6b23efe00] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speedloss
[output stream 0:0 @ 0x7fd6b0c2c2a0] 100 buffers queued in output stream 0:0, something may be wrong.
**ffmpeg(42836,0x7fff797f9300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fd6b0c34020: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug**
ffmpeg version 2.8.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=/usr/bin/clang --host-cflags='-Os -w -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.10' --host-ldflags='-L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names' --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-ffplay --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopus --enable-libquvi --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7faee1800000] moov atom not found
```

Comment: This looks like a bug you should report to [FFmpeg's bugtracker](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/). Before you do so though, you must try with the current git head by compiling it yourself or downloading it [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) (windows only). If it still happens, include the full command rather than those "cmd +=" bits in your bug report.

Comment: The issues was filed with FFmpegs bugtracker. This is now fixed in the latest git head -  8bcd1997eadb0d79a049227a1d1afe6111397baa.  You can reference the ticket at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5113.